# installing opencv3 for python3 in OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

So I followed [this tutorial](http://tsaith.github.io/install-opencv-3-for-python-3-on-osx.html) and got this error:

```
brew link --overwrite eigen
brew install opencv3 --with-python3 --with-contrib
```

wrote this in `~/.profile` and sourced it:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/lib/python3.4/site-packages
source ~/.profile
python3
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Can someone please guide me what is wrong and how to fix it?

UPDATE:

I tried this too:

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:build mona$ brew ln --force opencv3
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/opencv_annotation
Target /usr/local/bin/opencv_annotation
is a symlink belonging to opencv. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink opencv

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite opencv3

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run opencv3
Monas-MacBook-Pro:build mona$ brew link --overwrite opencv3
Warning: opencv3 is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
Monas-MacBook-Pro:build mona$ brew link --force --overwrite opencv3
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3... 551 symlinks created
```

Comment: Maybe try `cp /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/lib/python3.4/site-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/` ...

Comment: 'cp: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/lib/python3.4/site-packages/*: No such file or directory'

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed OpenCV3 using Homebrew, your symlink might be corrupted.

Since the current version of OpenCV in homebrew/science is 3.1.0, your symlink probably should point to

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

3.1.0_3 and python3.5 might differ on your system, so just see for yourself what directories are in /usr/local/Cellar.

BTW I didn't need to link anything after doing

```
brew ln --force opencv3
```

Comment: didn't work for me. Please check the updated question and what I tried after seeing your suggestion. However I still cannot import cv2

Comment: Worked great for me `brew ln --force opencv3`

Answer (score 0):

You need to **link** your opencv to python site-packages

Link **cv.py** and **cv2.so** using `ln -s [cellar-opencv-site-packages-path] [lib-python-site-packages-path]`

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.4.1/site-packages/cv.py /usr/local/lib/python3.4.1/site-packages/cv.py

ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.4.1/site-packages/cv2.so /usr/local/lib/python3.4.1/site-packages/cv2.so
```

Path will be based on opencv and python version.

Here it is - `[opencv3/3.1.0_3]` and `[python3.4.1]`

---

In short, Copy/Link **cv.py** and **cv2.so** from `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/[[version]]/lib/python[[version]]/site-packages/` to `/usr/local/lib/python[[version]]/site-packages/`

---

OR you can also add opencv site-packages to PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.4.1/site-packages/

source ~/.profile
```

Comment: my problem is I don't have python3.5 in Cellar directory. I only have python 2.7  `ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so` but in sys.path I have `['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', etc

Comment: Run - """ ls /usr/local/lib/python* """ AND """ ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/ """  AND """ ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/ """- What is the output?

Comment: my problem is I have no python3 in this directory `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/`

Comment: DO - """brew reinstall opencv3 --with-python3 --with-python2"""